# Depth test -opengl

Tags: opengl, shaders, graphics, depth-buffer

Does depth test runs before fragment shader,hence not even processing the fragment with frag shader if fragment is discarded
Or
It first runs the fragment shader and then depth test I.e. fragment shader runs for even the discarded frags.

If prior is false,then can it be achieved some how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is: **Both**.

If your fragment shader writes to `gl_FragDepth` it will do the depth test **after** your shader.

If you leave `gl_FragDepth` alone it will do the depth test **before** your shader.

source: https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/gl_FragDepth.xhtml

Comment: Also if you use the discard keyword anywhere, even conditionally it will prevent using early tests

Comment: If you don't use either and using GLSL430 or higher you can use layout(early_fragment_tests) in; to force using early tests, otherwise it's driver-dependand

Comment: @cozmic If you use the discard keyword the GPU can still do an early Z test and skip pixels (and the fragment shader) that would not show. It does not affect the regular depth test. What discard prevents is doing the full hidden surface removal on deferred tile renderers when the Z test passes.